# Refresh previous view using dismissModalViewControllerAnimated

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I am presenting a view say B using

```
 [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and from this view i am closing it to go back to view A using

```
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Now when i go back i want to call reload previous view (here view A). View A is tableview having list of data coming from the server. So reloadtable will not work,as new data can only come from server. So in short i want make that server call and refresh that view while closing View B.

How to do this.?

I have tried calling ViewDidLoad in ViewWillAppear method of view A,but it didn't work.

Please help in this.

EDIT :
My server call is like this

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"path"];

    NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%d%@%@", path,@"questions/?cat=",self.category,@"&que_language=",language];

NSString* encodedUrl = [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl];
NSLog(@"%@",address);

[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[URL host]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowedInMemoryOnly
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

// [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
//Write code you want to call when data is received,

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if (data) {
   NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
    int statuscode = [httpResponse statusCode];
    NSString *responseMsg = [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:statuscode];
    switch (statuscode) {
         case 200:{
            NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"data:%@",responseString);

            SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
            NSMutableArray *object = [parser objectWithString:responseString error:nil];

            questionList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init ];
            questions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init ];
            que_id = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init ];
            ans_count = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init ];

            int i=0;

            for (NSDictionary *quelist in object) {

                NSString *que = [quelist objectForKey:@"que_content"];
                NSString *queId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[quelist objectForKey:@"question_id"]] ;
                NSString *ansCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[quelist objectForKey:@"ans_count"]] ;

                [self.questions setValue:que forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
                [self.que_id setValue:queId forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
                [self.ans_count setValue:ansCount forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];

                [self.questionList setValue:que forKey:queId];

                i++;
            }
         break;
        }
    }
    [self.table reloadData];
    [self.table reloadInputViews];
  }
 }
```

EDIT 2 :

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    int rowNumber = indexPath.row;

    cell.textLabel.text = [questions valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowNumber]];

    NSString *ansCount = [ans_count valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowNumber]];

    UILabel *ans = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,39,100,12)];
    ans.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",ansCount,@" ",@"Answers"];
    ans.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0f] ;
    ans.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:ans];

    UIButton *showbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    showbtn.frame = CGRectMake(280, 10, 21, 21);
    showbtn.tag = rowNumber;

    [showbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [showbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetailedQuestion:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:showbtn];
}

// All bgColor configuration moves here

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.textColor  = [UIColor grayColor];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0f] ;


return cell;
}
```

Comment: Never directly call `viewDidLoad` or the other view controller methods.

Comment: @ani add your code in one method and call that function in viewwillappear.

Comment: I did that, and i am getting updated result. but unable to set it in my tableview. it just showing old data. I tried reloadData & setNeedDisplay. but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't call webservice in viewDidLoad use viewWillAppear for that so it get calls everytime view will appear and your problem will be disappear.

use this as per your Edit 2:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    int rowNumber = indexPath.row;

    cell.textLabel.text = [questions valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowNumber]];

    NSString *ansCount = [ans_count valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",rowNumber]];

    UILabel *ans = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,39,100,12)];
    ans.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",ansCount,@" ",@"Answers"];
    ans.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12.0f] ;
    ans.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:ans];

    UIButton *showbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    showbtn.frame = CGRectMake(280, 10, 21, 21);
    showbtn.tag = rowNumber;

    [showbtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [showbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetailedQuestion:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:showbtn];

    // All bgColor configuration moves here

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor  = [UIColor grayColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0f] ;


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am able to solve 50% of my problem now. I'm able to get updated result now, but unable to refresh view. i have tried [self.view setNeedsDisplay]; &  [self.table reloadData]. But nothing worked.

Comment: if you want to refresh your table then [self.table reloadData]; is perfect and should give you the updated result but make sure you use this statement at proper place. if you're calling web-service in viewWillAppear then use table reload at the end of your response from web.

Comment: yes i have just write that line below web service call. though it didn't worked. then why ?

Comment: ohh not under webservice call but at the end of your web-service call like where your web-service call gets response or in such kind of success method, okay i'll give you an example 

    -(void)fetchDataSuccessForForgotPassword:(NSMutableData *)data
{
}

this method i call when my webservice call responds successfully so i reload my table inside this.

Comment: NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowedInMemoryOnly timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if(data){
// here i'm setting data
}

[self.table relaodData];

Comment: then i guess you might have this delegate method 

    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
}

if yes then reload your table inside this with your desired modification.

Comment: i tried there too. even its not working. what could be the reason.

Comment: @Ani have tried to helped you as much as i can but sorry can't figure out without code and testing..

Comment: i have label in tableviewcell, is it could be the reason ? if yes how to solve  this ?

Comment: neah i don't think that's the problem. if you can share your code then i might be able to help you out by trying something in that so if you don't mind then share it with me.

Comment: this might seems to be work as your code has no mistakes....whats the issue you won't get your desired output on table after second time web-service call?

Comment: yes that the problem. its not refreshing in cell. however in NSLog i can see the new values.

Comment: put you cellforrowatindexpath method in your question as edit2

Comment: @Ani i've edited my answer let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks friend it worked.. :) But just couldn't get what you have edited. Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: welcome friend :) i'm happy that you achieved your desired output...i've just edited one line :D

Comment: Ya i got that "}"; Thanks again... :)

Answer (score 3):

You have several options:

1. If it is iPhone-only or is being presented full screen, you can wait for `viewDidAppear` to be called.
2. You can implement a `refresh` call on A, and then in B, on `viewDidDisappear`, you can see if B's `presentingViewController` `respondsToSelector:@selector(refresh)`, and if so, call `refresh` on the `presentingViewController`.
3. You can post some notification from B and listen for it from A.

Answer (score 2):

Use this method:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                    //Reload the table view here
                }];
```

(The method you are using is deprecated.)